# QGIS: Automatically adding thousands of points with random coordinates

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to create a points shapefile with thousands of features, each with a randomised marker size and coordinate (imagine a field of different-sized craters). I can randomise the marker size, but I'm not sure how to get QGIS to:

a) Add point features without manually adding each one; I want to just tell it to generate 10,000 points

b) Add each feature at a random coordinate with defined limits (e.g. at randf(0, 4000000) / randf(0,2000000) in map units)

I'm aware of the "random points in layer bounds" etc. tools, but for some reason this is placing multiple features directly on top of each other, so I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: What are the map units, and what is the extent?  If you're working in degrees, you really ought to compensate for the fact that portions closer to the poles have smaller area, and therefore would be overrepresented  by a simple random function. Please [Edit] the question to focus on a single issue.

Comment: If you don't want intersecting shapes, i.e. the distribution is not fully random anymore, you can generate more points and exclude the overlaps

Comment: you should set the minimum distance in the random points algorithm according to your maximum marker size. then you won't get features on top of each other.

Comment: @ThomasB I think you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Set the minimum distance in the random points algorithm according to your maximum marker size. then you won't get features on top of each other.

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried this and still get the same results. I'm about to post a question demonstrating this once QGIS lets me in 40 mins.